# Parallel.ForEach over AuthorizationRuleCollection

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, access-rules

Hopefully someone could point out what I am doing wrong here.  I have a process that reads in file access rules and I am trying to run it in Parallel.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public List<FolderAccessRule> GetSecurityGroupsForFolder(long importId, string subdirectory, bool includeInherited)
    {
        ConcurrentQueue<FolderAccessRule> groups = new ConcurrentQueue<FolderAccessRule>();
        ConcurrentQueue<Exception> exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subdirectory);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        AuthorizationRuleCollection authorizationRuleCollection = dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, includeInherited, typeof(NTAccount));
        Parallel.ForEach( authorizationRuleCollection,
            fsar =>
            {
                try
                {
                    FolderAccessRule group = this.GetGroup(fsar);
                    if (group != null)
                    {
                        groups.Enqueue(group);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    exceptions.Enqueue(e);
                }
            });

        foreach (Exception e in exceptions)
        {
            string message = string.Concat(e.GetType(), "Exception getting Directory info for  ", subdirectory);
            this.RecordException(message, subdirectory, e);
        }

        return groups.ToList();
    }
```

Which (to the untrained eye),  looks like it should work.  But the `Parallel.ForEach` will not compile as it gives the error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Action<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I have also tried changing the offending line to:

```
Parallel.ForEach<FileSystemAccessRule>( authorizationRuleCollection, fsar =>
```

But still no joy.

So,  what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the only error? Uncomment code until it goes away. That tells you what's wrong. Post the reduced code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `authorizationRuleCollection.OfType<AuthorizationRule>()` to `Parallel.ForEach`, eg:

```
var typedColletion=authorizationRuleCollection.OfType<AuthorizationRule>();
Parallel.ForEach(typedColletion);
```

The error is caused because [`AuthorizationRuleCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrulecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't implement [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) but only [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), whose elements are `Object`. This is a common pattern with older (pre - .NET 2.0) collections, when generics weren't available.

Newer .NET classes return/expect generic collections. By calling [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) you effectively cast the source `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The difference is that [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) will filter out incompatible elements, while [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) will throw if any incompatible elements are found.

The [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ba4a3f8a5530e33,references) behind both methods isn't magic, in the reference source it's simply an iterator over the source `IEnumerable`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
        foreach (object obj in source) {
            if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Genius - thanks.  that is exactly the answer I was looking for :)